# Silverlight, calculate shape Height & Width using persentage

Tags: silverlight, layout, canvas, grid

I have a silverlight application that works but I now need to resize some items using a percentage instead of using fixed Height and Width.

My code snippit for this is:

```
    private void drawCell(int row, int col, string label, Color fill)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Height = cellSize;
        rect.Width = cellSize;
        rect.StrokeThickness = 2;
        rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(fill);

        Grid.Children.Add(rect);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, col * cellSize);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, row * cellSize);

        Rectangle innertec = new Rectangle();
        innertec.Height = cellSize - 30;
        innertec.Width = cellSize - 10;
        innertec.StrokeThickness = 1;
        innertec.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        innertec.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(fill);
        innertec.Margin = new Thickness(5);

        Grid.Children.Add(innertec);
        Canvas.SetLeft(innertec, col * cellSize);
        Canvas.SetTop(innertec, row * cellSize);

        Border productLabelBorder = new Border();

        TextBlock productLabel = new TextBlock();
        productLabel.Height = cellSize - 60;
        productLabel.Width = cellSize - 10;
        productLabel.Margin = new Thickness(5, innertec.Height + 5, 0, 5);
        productLabel.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        productLabel.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        productLabel.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.WordEllipsis;
        productLabel.Text = label;
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(productLabel, label);

        productLabelBorder.Child = productLabel;

        Grid.Children.Add(productLabelBorder);
        Canvas.SetLeft(productLabelBorder, col * cellSize);
        Canvas.SetTop(productLabelBorder, row * cellSize);
    }
```

What I want the code to do is take the innertec and productLabel, and calculate the Height and Width by first looking at the cellSize (which is a variable set elsewhere) and then create these objects with a percentage of cellSize.

The reason for this is that cellSize changed size depending on a slider in the UI. The "cells" resize after calculating the area of the Canvas.

Is it possible to calculate these values as a percentage?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using your Grid correctly! I can see you are adding items to the Grid, then trying to position them via the Canvas attached properties. You are mixing two different panel types!

With the Canvas, children are positions by their Top and Left coordinates

With the Grid children are located within cells as indicated by the Grid.Row and Grid.Column attached property.

You can use 'star' widths and heights to define the proportional width and height of rows / columns in order have grid cells which are some percentage of the overall grid. For example in markup, if you want to add a grid cell which is 50% of the overall grid size you can do the following:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions

  <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="foo"/>
</Grid>
```

With the above, the Button will have a width which is 50% of the overall Grid width.

Comment: Sorry, my naming convention is confusing. As I was originally using a grid and now swtiched to Canvas but I have left the Canvas x:name as Grid (it builds a grid but still confusing).

Comment: Anyway, I have fixed this now by using calculations for the cells that my code creates and adds to the canvas.